# Returning JSON from action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have this action methid. It will return some JSON.

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
        ...

        return new JsonResult { Data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };  
}
```

Then I have in my view a script tag pointing to the Get action method.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/resource/get")"></script>
```

The problem is I can't access the JSON data in JS code. It seems like the JSON needs to be executed somehow. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You do know that you can just go `return Json(data);` right? :)

Comment: I know, but you have to set JsonRequestBehavior anyway.

Comment: so why not decorate the method with the `[HttpGet]` attribute?

Comment: You have to set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet anyway..

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the action in jQuery and then process the Json directly:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/resource/get",
  success: function(data){
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  }
});
```

Or a shorter version:

```
$.getJSON('/resource/get', function(data) { 
    var obj = data;
});
```

Comment: I know that, but I just wondering if there were any other way ? Maybe a mvc html helper ?

Comment: What's wrong with this way? Is there a specific need you're trying to solve? Could you tell me why you want to do it with the script reference instead of just calling it through Ajax?

Comment: I just want to have the JSON object to be ready as soon as possible.

Comment: Then why not execute this method immediately on document.ready?

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid. It's 10 lines of JS just to load some JSON.

Comment: You could also use $.getJSON, I've added an example to the answer, which is only 3 lines. But anyway, the difference is not that big is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the JSON available ASAP, without an extra request, include it in the initial page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJson = @Html.Action("Get");
</script>
```

Now you can just access the `myJson` variable in your script to access your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be dumped into your HTML at the time the page is built on the server, you can add it to your view model, then render it directly on the page. Here's a pseudo-code example:

```
<script type="javascript">
     var obj= JSON.parse('@Model.PropertyContainingJson');
</script>
```